# Campos do objeto nulo ao tentar persistir com JSF e JPA

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jpa

Estou tentando persistir uma entidade e quando tento persistir ele joga um erro de constraint violation, realizando o debug, notei que o objeto é instanciado porem os campos estão nulos.

Entidades:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PessoaAbstract implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column
private Date dataNascimento;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(nullable = false)
@NotNull
private DomSexo sexo;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj instanceof PessoaAbstract) {
        PessoaAbstract outroPes = (PessoaAbstract) obj;

        return outroPes.id.equals(id);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Date getDataNascimento() {
    return dataNascimento;
}

public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
    this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
}

public DomSexo getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(DomSexo sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}


@Entity
public class Consultor extends PessoaAbstract{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

public enum DomSexo {

M("Masculino"), F("Feminino");

private final String label;

private DomSexo(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}
}
```

DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class ConsultorDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

 public void salvar(Consultor consultor) {
    this.em.persist(consultor);
 }
}
```

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ConsultorBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Consultor consultor;

@Inject
private ConsultorDao consultorDao;

@PostConstruct
public void iniciaDao() {
    consultor = new Consultor();
}

public void gravaConsultor() {
    consultorDao.salvar(consultor);
}

public DomSexo[] getSexo() {
    return DomSexo.values();
}

public Consultor getConsultor() {
    return consultor;
}

public void setConsultor(Consultor consultor) {
    this.consultor = consultor;
}
}
```

View:

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Cadastro</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">

    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />

        <p:wizard >

            <p:tab id="dadosPessoais" title="Dados Pessoais">
                <p:panel header="Dados">
                    <p:messages />

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, valor">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Nome" />
                        <p:inputText  label="Nome" value="#{consultorBean.consultor.nome}"/>

                        <p:outputLabel value="Sexo" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="sexo" value="#{consultorBean.consultor.sexo}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecionar"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{consultorBean.sexo}" var="tipoSexo" itemLabel="#{tipoSexo.label}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel value="Data de nascimento" for="dataNascimento" />
                        <p:calendar id="dataNascimento" label="Data de nascimento" value="#{consultorBean.consultor.dataNascimento}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="confirmacao" title="Confirmação">
                <p:panel header="Confirmação">
                    <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" action="#{consultorBean.gravaConsultor()}" process="@this" />
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>
        </p:wizard>

    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

Mensagem do console:

```
21:38:43,252 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-39) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.jrHandle(ServletInitialHandler.java)
at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.servlet.undertow.cbp.ServletInitialHandlerCBP.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandlerCBP.java:101)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:139)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:119)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at br.com.livraria.aldebaran.dao.ConsultorDao$$$view1.salvar(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:401)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
at br.com.livraria.aldebaran.dao.ConsultorDao$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.salvar(Unknown Source)
at br.com.livraria.aldebaran.controller.ConsultorBean.gravaConsultor(ConsultorBean.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:93)
... 96 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: error during managed flush
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:358)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166)
... 99 more
 Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [br.com.livraria.aldebaran.model.Consultor] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=sexo, rootBeanClass=class br.com.livraria.aldebaran.model.Consultor, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=nome, rootBeanClass=class br.com.livraria.aldebaran.model.Consultor, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:218)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:97)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110)
... 105 more
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar um ajax false no seu botão de confirmação? E se mudar o escopo do seu bean, é possível salvar?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema; a falha estava no escopo utilizado, alterei para `@ViewScoped` para resolver essa situação.